# How to add arraylist in hashmap in java using object of class

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap

I want to write a program ask the user to enter numerator and denominator and store them in a matrix and arrange it by hashmap the following is the question I wrote the code but I still have wrongs:

Develop a public class `Matrix` according to the following specifications [14 marks]
The `Matrix` class represents matrix of the fraction `Number` to the following specifications and for example the size of the matrix as 2 rows x 3 columns

1. The class has a private instance variable `HashMap <Integer,
   ArrayList<Number>>`, which represents the collection of numbers from
   class `Number`. where Integer represents the number of rows- 2 as in
   the example above. `ArrayList<Number>` contains the values of the
   fraction `Numbers` of `Number` class (the elements in each row)
2. The class has 2 static public instance variables rows and cols.
   where rows represents the number of rows in the matrix. Cols
   represents the number of elements in the `ArrayList` of each row.
3. The class has a two-argument constructor that creates and
   initializes `HashMap <Integer, ArrayList<Number>>` instance object and
   set the values of rows and cols by the given values as arguments.
4. The class has a public method void `fillMatrix ( )`. The method
   uses the `Scanner` class to fill the objects of `Number` in the matrix
   according to the number of items in each row.
5. The class has a public method `printMatrix()`. It displays the
   items of the matrix as rows and columns as highlighted above
6. The class has a public method `Number` `getItem(int rowNO, int colNO)`
   which gets and returns the specific number item in the matrix
   according to the given argument.

EX. `getItem(2, 3) returns __`

```
import java.util.*;
public class Matrix extends Number{

    private HashMap <Integer, ArrayList<Number>> hMap;
    public static int rows;
    public static int cols;

   public Matrix(int r,int c){

        hMap = new HashMap <Integer, ArrayList<Number>>();
        rows = r;
        cols = c;
    }
    public void fillMatrix () {

        ArrayList<Number> numarr = new ArrayList<Number>();
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        for(int i = 1; i <= rows; i++){
            for(int j = 1; j <= cols; j++){

                System.out.print("Enter Nomerator");
                int nom = input.nextInt();

                System.out.print("Enter Denomerator");
                int denom = input.nextInt();
                numarr.add(new Number(nom,denom));

            }
        }
        for(int i = 1; i <= rows; i++){
            for(int j = 1; j <= cols; j++){
                hMap.put(j, numarr.get(i));
            }
        }
       System.out.print(hMap);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you suppose to store in your matrix the fraction of the product of dividing the numerator over the denominator, it is not clear what are you doing with the add(new Number(nom, denom));, this constructor of Number does not exist.  Why does Matrix extends from Number. This is not clear, please clarify your question.

Comment: there are a nother class named "Number" calculate addition and subtraction of fractions and has setter , getter and to string methods I have no problem with it but this question is connected to it I should use an object belong to Number class to make an array using hashmap. The array should have columns and rows I filled the array but I couldn't sort it in columns and rows .

Comment: 1/2  3/4  5/2
"new line"
3/6  4/8  1/2
The array should be like this

Comment: That is because the way you are populating the Hashmap is incorrect, I can add few lines of  code in answer the way should be populating the Hashmap using your existing code, let me know if it is not working for you, then I can remove the answer,  You may want to show your Number class code, because your question is not clear and the class Number conflicts with the Java class Number